# hp printer laser jet pro? mfp m125nw

Tags: hp

When I ran the program `hp-setup` I got the following output:

```
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.16.3)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

error: HPLIP is not installed properly or is installed without graphical support. Please reinstall HPLIP
warning: Qt/PyQt 4 initialization failed.
error: hp-setup requires GUI support (try running with --qt3). Also, try using interactive (-i) mode.
```

[my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1Zl9.png)

How can I fix this error?

Comment: what version of Ubuntu is this?

Answer (score 0):

Hp printers require `qt4` installed so install with:

```
sudo apt install python-qt4
```

Then run the `hp-setup` again.

Comment: this shows up E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: Please restart the system or wait a few minutes to gain access. Another update process has a lock on that dir

Comment: I think I've just realized what's wrong, I tried to add it from Settings-Printers and it worked. I think there was something wrong at first but it's done now.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 17.04, HPLip 3.16.11, I needed to:

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4 python3-pip
pip3 install pyqt5
```

After that, HP-Setup does run in a graphical mode

Comment: this shows upE: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?